# How to show fixed string in UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

How to show fixed string in UIPickerView ?

like kg, cm , mmHg....

look like this http://hazelnut.atnifty.com/iphone-app/bptwit  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:
http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/2009/03/a-uipickerview-with-labels/